# get curl request to eBay Post Order API giving empty string (PHP)

Tags: php, curl, ebay-api, php-curl

GET /post-order/v2/casemanagement/{caseId} call of eBay Post Order API  giving an empty string. Can anyone clear out where does my code go wrong? Am I passing the headers correctly? Especially is the syntax of authorization correct?

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);  // Turn on all errors, warnings and notices for easier debugging

//Seller Authorization Token
$userAuthToken= 'Authorization:TOKEN abc123';

//Endpoint URL to Use
$url = "https://api.ebay.com/post-order/v2/casemanagement/xyz";

//Initializle cURL
$connection = curl_init();

//Set Endpoint URL
curl_setopt($connection,CURLOPT_URL,$url);

//Set HTTP Method
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);

//Create Array of  Required Headers
$headers = array();
$headers[] = $userAuthToken;
$headers[] = 'Content-Type:application/json';
$headers[] = 'X-EBAY-C-MARKETPLACE-ID:EBAY-DE';
//var_dump($headers);
//set the headers using the array of headers
curl_setopt($connection,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);

//set it to return the transfer as a string from curl_exec
curl_setopt($connection,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

//stop CURL from verifying the peer's certificate
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

//Execute the Request
$response = curl_exec($connection);

//close the connection
curl_close($connection);

var_dump($response);
```

Comment: did you find a solution for your problem, I have the same one??
Regard's

Comment: Stop turning off CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER and fix your PHP config. Anyone running a recent Linux distribution is probably already OK, because they get the curl libraries bundled in through their package managers and recent curl libraries come with the latest CA root certificate bundle from Mozilla.org. This means you can just turn CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER on and you won’t get any errors.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code it is working fine for me.

```
<?php
         // Your ID and token
         $authToken = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

         // The data to send to the API
         $post_data = json_encode(array("legacyOrderId"=>"110181400870-27973775001"));
         $url = 'https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/post-order/v2/cancellation/check_eligibility'; 
         //Setup cURL
         $header = array(
                        'Accept: application/json',
                        'Authorization: TOKEN '.$authToken,
                        'Content-Type: application/json',
                        'X-EBAY-C-MARKETPLACE-ID: EBAY-UK'
                         );
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        if(curl_errno($ch)){
            echo "ERROR:".curl_error($ch);
        }
        curl_close($ch); 
        echo json_decode($response,true);
     ?>
```

Response:

```
 Array
(
    [legacyOrderId] => 110181400870-27973775001
    [eligible] => 1
    [failureReason] => Array
        (
        )

    [itemEligibilityResult] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [itemId] => 110181400870
                    [transactionId] => 34573775001
                    [eligible] => 1
                    [failureReason] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

    [eligibleCancelReason] => Array
        (
            [0] => OUT_OF_STOCK_OR_CANNOT_FULFILL
            [1] => BUYER_CANCEL_OR_ADDRESS_ISSUE
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

ADD
`curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);`

To return the headers and see what your problem might be.

I also don't know if it matters but my headers array looks like:

`$headers = array (
'Authorization: ' . "TOKEN $token",
'Content-Type: ' . 'application/json',
'X-EBAY-C-MARKETPLACE-ID: ' . 'EBAY-US',
'Accept: ' . 'application/json',
);`

So you can see there is a space after the colon.